# Error while executing cms-import.ps1 using WEB 8.1.1 and DXA 1.4

Tags: dxa, web8, dxa-1.4

Web 8.1.1 is successfully installed demo visitorWeb site is running. Now,I am trying to setup the DXA 1.4 demo site when importing the CMS content by running **cms-import.ps1** Followed the steps described [SDL docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v3&lang=en-US&docid=GUID-8F9431EC-C1C0-40CE-8315-05AB0E77FE7A&query=%2B%22dxa%201.3%22#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA.xml&docid=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA) getting following   error 
 i have tried running powershell with run as different user as well

**CMS-import.ps1 is installed successfully**

The issue has been resolved  and cms content are installed successfully and default home page is published successfully as described [here](https://community.sdl.com/products-solutions/solutions/customer_experience_cloud/digital-experience/tridion/w/web8-training/902.how-to-install-dxa-v1-3-in-a-web-8-environment)

But when browsing the site http://localhost:8888/index.html getting authentication error below are site.log and cd_client.log

I tried this as well
**`<add key="oauth-enabled" value="true"/>`**

**CD_client.log**

```
2016-06-02 12:57:37 ERROR [Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider..ctor]
        Problem authenticating with service. Please make sure your authentication settings are correct and you have enabled authentication.
```

**and**
**site.log**

```
2016-06-02 12:57:37,345 [1] ERROR - An error occurred while processing this request.
Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceClientException: {"error":"invalid_grant"}
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.ReturnSingleton[TElement](Expression expression)
   at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.Caller.ODataContextEngineServiceClient..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Context.OData.Client.ODataContextEngine..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.Context.ContextServiceClaimsProvider..cctor() in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\Context\ContextServiceClaimsProvider.cs:line 32
2016-06-02 12:57:37,568 [8] ERROR - Unauthorized Request -- Please check your configuration settings to make sure your authentication details are correct.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Unauthorized Request -- Please check your configuration settings to make sure your authentication details are correct.
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.DiscoveryService.DiscoveryServiceClient.get_ContentServiceUri()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.AutoConfigure.get_ServiceEndpoint()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.AutoConfigure.get_ODataV4ServiceEndpoint()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider.get_Instance()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:line 66
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 23
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 51
2016-06-02 12:57:37,720 [10] ERROR - Unauthorized Request -- Please check your configuration settings to make sure your authentication details are correct.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Unauthorized Request -- Please check your configuration settings to make sure your authentication details are correct.
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1 block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.DiscoveryService.DiscoveryServiceClient.get_ContentServiceUri()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.AutoConfigure.get_ServiceEndpoint()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.AutoConfigure.get_ODataV4ServiceEndpoint()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider..ctor()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.ContentService.ContentServiceProvider.get_Instance()
   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.DynamicMappingsRetrieverImpl.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.DynamicMappingsRetriever.GetPublicationMapping(String url)
   at Sdl.Web.Tridion.CdApiLocalizationResolver.ResolveLocalization(Uri url) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Tridion\CdApiLocalizationResolver.cs:line 66
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Configuration.WebRequestContext.get_Localization() in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Configuration\WebRequestContext.cs:line 23
   at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Statics.StaticContentModule.BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Jenkins\workspace\DXA Dev CI Web App .NET\Sdl.Web.Mvc\Statics\StaticContentModule.cs:line 51
```

**ERROR**

```
PS E:\DXA 1.4\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms> .\cms-import.ps1 -importType all-publications -cmsUrl http://web8.domain.com/
Uploading package 'E:\DXA 1.4\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\web8\all-publications.zip' ...
Importing content ...
Aborted
2016-05-31 18:10:44 <52> [Information] Import process 'b7558b26a9f749709b80a848475aeb90' is started by 'Domain\mtsuser' at 5/31/2016 6:10:44 PM.
2016-05-31 18:10:44 <52> [Information] Building list of items to import and determining required import actions.
2016-05-31 18:10:44 <52> [Information] Unzipping and initializing package for import.
2016-05-31 18:10:50 <52> [Information] Import of system administration items started at 5/31/2016 6:10:50 PM.
2016-05-31 18:10:50 <52> [Information] Import items into publication '000 Empty' started at 5/31/2016 6:10:50 PM.
2016-05-31 18:11:13 <52> [Information] Import items into publication '100 Master' started at 5/31/2016 6:11:13 PM.
2016-05-31 18:12:04 <52> [Information] Import items into publication '110 DXA Site Type' started at 5/31/2016 6:12:04 PM.
2016-05-31 18:12:06 <52> [Error] Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServi
ceClientException: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<title>IIS 8.5 Detailed Error - 500.19 - Internal Server Error</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
<!-- 
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;} 
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;} 
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;} 
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;} 
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;} 
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;} 
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;} 
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;} 
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;} 
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px; 
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;} 
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;} 
a:hover{text-decoration:none;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;} 
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;} 
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0; 
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif; 
 color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2; 
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;} 
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;} 
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0; 
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%; 
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden; 
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF; 
 background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal; 
 font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right; 
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;} 
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;} 
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;} 
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;} 
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%; 
}#details-right th{width:20%;} 
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{} 
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;} 
.clear{clear:both;} 
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;} 
--> 
</style> 

</head> 
<body> 
<div id="content"> 
<div class="content-container"> 
  <h3>HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error</h3> 
  <h4>The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.</h4> 
</div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4> 
  <div id="details-left"> 
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;IIS Web Core</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Unknown</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Not yet determined</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x80070003</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Config Error</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cannot read configuration file
</td></tr> 
<tr><th>Config File</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\\?\E:\Websites\dxa\web.config</td></tr> 
   </table> 
  </div> 
  <div id="details-right"> 
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://localhost:82/ttm201501/CdTopologyTypes</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr> 
    <tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Not yet determined</td></tr> 
    <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Not yet determined</td></tr> 

   </table> 
   <div class="clear"></div> 
  </div> 
 </fieldset> 
</div> 
  <div class="config_source content-container"> 
    <fieldset> 
    <h4>Config Source:</h4> 
    <pre><code>   -1: 
<span class="highlight-code">    0: </span>
</code></pre> 
    </fieldset> 
  </div> 

<div class="content-container"> 
 <fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4> 
  This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more informat
ion about what caused this error. 
  <p><a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=500,19,0x80070003,9600">View more information &raquo;</a></p> 

 </fieldset> 
</div> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html> 

   at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.BusinessProcessType.OnSaved(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.<>c__DisplayClass2.<InvokeInErrorHandler>b__1(Boolean isRetry)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.AbortErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply 
additionalUserReplyOptions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.InvokeInErrorHandler[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportAction.SaveItem(IdentifiableObject item, IdentifiableObjectData deltaObject)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.CreateImportAction.Perform(IdentifiableObjectData itemData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImpor
t)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImpor
t)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImpor
t)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItem(WebDavUrl exportUrl, IList`1 dependentItemsChain, Dictionary`2 unresolvedDependencies, Boolean specialImpor
t)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.ImportItems(IList`1 items, Boolean specialGroupImport)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Importer.Import(String packageName)
2016-05-31 18:12:06 <52> [Information] Transactional import failed at 5/31/2016 6:12:06 PM. No changes were committed to SDL Web Content Manager.
An error occured while importing 'E:\DXA 1.4\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\web8\all-publications.zip'
At E:\DXA 1.4\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\ImportExport\ContentManagerUtils.ps1:402 char:9
+         throw "An error occured while importing '$packageFullPath'"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (An error occure...blications.zip':String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : An error occured while importing 'E:\DXA 1.4\SDL DXA .NET 1.4\cms\web8\all-publications.zip'
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow! That is confusing!

From the Stack Trace you can see that the error occurs when trying to save a Business Process Type in COntent Manager (DXA 1.3+ indeed comes with predefined BPTs).

This triggers validation against Topology Manager (to check that the associated Topology Type exists) as can be seen in the (HTML) error: `http://localhost:82/ttm201501`

But then that same (HTML) error message mentions a problem with your DXA Web Application's configuration: `E:\Websites\dxa\web.config`

So, the question is: is http://localhost:82 your Topology Manager website or your DXA website (or neither)? It looks like CM expects it to be your Topology Manager website (check your `TRIDION_TTM_WEBSITE_URL` Environment variable) but the error suggests it's not.

Did you maybe deploy the DXA Web Application inside your Topology Manager website?

Comment: thanks for the response there was some issue with topology manager site which i have resolved and cms content installation is done  successfully and Home page is published successfully but when browsing the site we are getting error i have updated the question

Comment: It would have been much better to create a new Question for your second, completely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your second question: the error message is quite explicit - either OAuth is disabled or the OAuth credentials you specified don't match those configured for your CIS Environment.